# Get specific field from one to many table relationship with laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

I have table like this following image:
[image]

so, user have many `balance_transactions` and last inserted `balance_transactions` record will be user account balance. my question, how to make `user model` have property account_balance with value last inserted `total` in `balance_transactions` table

I was tried using something like this in user model

```
public function balance {
    return $this->hasMany(App\BalanceTransaction::class);
}

public function account_balance {
    return $this->balance()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(1);
}
```

And I get the data like this

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->with('account_balance')->first();
return response()->json($user);
```

and the result look like this folowing json:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "username": "john0131",
   "full_name": "john doe",
   "email": john@test.com,
   "account_balance": [
      {
          "id": 234,
          "user_id": 1,
          "total": 7850
          "added_value": 50
          "created_date": "2020-02-28 12:18:18"
      }
   ]
}
```

but what I want, the return should be like this following json:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "username": "john0131",
   "full_name": "john doe",
   "email": "john@test.com",
   "account_balance": 7850
}
```

my question, how to make something like that in laravel eloquent proper way? so I can get `account_balance` data only with simple code like `$user = user::find(1);`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest loading only one row from your transaction table with an eye on performance. Additionally you can append the value of the accessor to the serialised output of the model (e.g. `__toArray()`) and return the acutal value only if the relationship has already been loaded.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $appends = ['account_balance'];

    public function balance()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\BalanceTransaction::class);
    }

    public function latestBalance()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasOne(App\BalanceTransaction::class)
            ->latest();
    }

    public function getAcountBalanceAttribute()
    {
        if (! $this->relationLoaded('latestBalance')) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->latestBalance->total;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why `!$this->relationLoaded('latestBalance')` always return false.. but with litle modification it's work... Thank you verry much Dan

Comment: Hey, I've found my mistake. I named the method of the relation wrong. If you now eager load the relation it should work correctly.

Comment: The highlighted one: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60954385/revisions

Comment: Oh...Okay @Dan ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way to tackle this is, you could use laravel [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

So in your User model you can create a method as follows

```
/**
 * Get the user's balance.
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getAccountBalanceAttribute()
{
    return $this->balance->last()->total;
}
```

then wherever you want to use it you can use it by:
$user->account_balance;

Comment: That won't work like this. Accessors could be a way but you gotta remember the `balance`-relation returns a collection.

Comment: @Dan. Yes thanks for pointing out. We can use the last() method on the collection then.